# HTML anchors in iframe not working in Chrome or Safari

Tags: html, css, iframe

First off I do not consider myself to be anything more than a hack at HTML/CSS.  With that said , I am having a problem with the attached code in Chrome and Safari (Firefox and Opera work perfectly fine). The problem is clicking on one of the help icons in the center iframe should send the right iframe to the appropriate anchor, but it does not.  I would like the help topics to move from topic to topic without a scroll bar.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Lorem ipsum dolor</title>
<link href="apstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="Body">
    <div class="leftnav"><p>Something</p></div>
    <div class="main"><iframe src="Setup.html" name="main" id="main" width="450" height="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe></div>
    <div class="right"><iframe src="Help.html" name="help" id="help" width="235" height="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Setup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link href="apstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="options">
    <p>Get Help #2
    <a href="Help.html#help2" target="help">
        <img src="helpicon16.png" alt="help2" class="help_icon"/>
    </a>
    </p>
    <p>Get Help #3
    <a href="Help.html#help3" target="help">
        <img src="helpicon16.png" alt="help3" class="help_icon"/>
    </a>
    </p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and the css

```
@charset "UTF-8";

.Body {
float : left;
clear : both;
width : 100%;
margin-top : 5px;
margin-bottom : 5px;
}

.leftnav {
float : left;
height : 500px;
width : 155px;
margin-left : 25px;
background-color : #eae6e3;
}

.main {
float : left;
height : 500px;
width : 445px;
margin-left : 5px;
}
.right {
clear : right;
float : left;
height : 500px;
width : 185px;
margin-left : 5px;
}

iframe.help {
overflow : hidden;
}

div.spacer {
height: 1000px;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

I suppose adding the Help.html might make this easier to replicate

Help.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Help</title>
<link href="apstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="HelpPage">
<h2>Help Stuff</h2>

<a id="help1"></a>
<h3>Help #1</h3>
<p>This is help #1</p>
<div class="spacer"></div>

<a id="help2"></a>
<h3>Help #2</h3>
<p>This is help #2</p>
<div class="spacer"></div>

<a id="help3"></a>
<h3>Help #3</h3>
<p>This is help #3</p>
<div class="spacer"></div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Works fine in Opera 11, Firefor 14, Safari 5 and Chrome 20 under Windows.

Comment: Verified not working in Chrome 21 (windows) and Safari 6 (mac)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove :

```
scrolling="no"
```

and it works for Chrome 21 on windows.

**Edit**

Still remove the `scrolling="no"` but change the html code for `Help.html` to this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Help</title>
<link href="apstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<style>
html {
    overflow:hidden;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="HelpPage">
<h2>Help Stuff</h2>

<a id="help1"></a>
<h3>Help #1</h3>
<p>This is help #1</p>
<div class="spacer"></div>

<a id="help2"></a>
<h3>Help #2</h3>
<p>This is help #2</p>
<div class="spacer"></div>

<a id="help3"></a>
<h3>Help #3</h3>
<p>This is help #3</p>
<div class="spacer"></div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

See here: [testing.dpwebdev.co.uk/stackoverflow/anchors](http://testing.dpwebdev.co.uk/stackoverflow/anchors/)

Comment: Thanks David but I should have stated earlier that having the scrollbar next to the help is unacceptable.  Also in your test the css definition for the spacer is deleted so the entire help fits in the window.

Comment: Thanks David!  Works just like I wanted it to.